# Sheets().Range() gives error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a script in VBA for excel 2010.

I simply want to get the average of a range of data in a *different sheet*.

The following is the line of code giving me problems:

```
Cells(2, 11).Value = Application.Average(Sheets(1).Range(Cells(356, 6), Cells(365, 6)))
```

Which gives "Run-time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error".

Note that this next line works fine, but it gets the data from the wrong sheet:

```
Cells(2, 11).Value = Application.Average(Range(Cells(356, 6), Cells(365, 6)))
```

I have googled my butt off but I cannot find the correct way to reference the first sheet (not by name) while calculating the average of a range.

By itself, `Sheets(1).Cells(...)` doesn't cause an error. So I tried:

```
Cells(2, 11).Value = Application.Average(Range(Sheets(1).Cells(356, 6), Sheets(1).Cells(365, 6)))
```

...but I get the same original error (1004).

How can I get the average of the range of data from the first sheet?

Comment: Is your first sheet actually named 1? Try giving it a name and passing the string value to Sheets()

Comment: EVERY range object, which includes `Cells` needs to have the parent sheet expressed. `ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 11).Value = Application.Average(Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(356, 6), Sheets(1).Cells(365, 6)))`

Comment: @JacobH - calling them by string doesn't work either. For that matter, it shouldn't make a difference since sheets(1) works fine when I don't need a range.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Your solution worked! Note though that the first ActiveSheet (on the left side of the '='  was not needed.

Comment: @Bort you are correct if the range object is on the active sheet then it is not needed, but it is good practice to always explicitly name the parent with all range objects.  I will always give answers that explicitly give the parent of the range objects even when it is `ActiveSheet`